# Почему не работает from

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь понять Intra-package References
Дерево проекта:

```
project/
       __init__.py
       main.py
       folder/
              __init__.py
              module_1.py
              module_2.py
```

В "module_2.py пишу:

```
def one():
    return 1
```

В "module_1.py пишу:

```
from . import module_2
print(module_2.one())
```

остальные файлы пустые

ошибка

Comment: Какая именно ошибка?

Comment: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: А запускаете вы какой вообще модуль?

Comment: я запускаю module_1

Comment: Тогда может просто `import module_2` надо делать?

Comment: я хочу понять почему именно через "from . import module_2" не работает

Comment: Возможно, это может быть связанно с использованием виртуальной машины или что-то такого. Если надо то больше информации [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/339220/13940541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При запуске скрипта интерпретатор не знает родительский пакет, и потому относительный импорт не работает.

Если скрипт не верхнего уровня (а данном случае это так), то можно запустить скрипт как модуль: `python -m folder.module_1`, тогда питон будет знать родительский пакет.

Еще вариант явно провисать в модуле родительский пакет до относительного импорта:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = 'folder'
```

В таком случае даже `python folder/module_1.py` будет работать при условии, что директория верхнего уровня указана в `PYTHONPATH`.

Подробности описаны [тут](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/)